# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'email' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

`1.`models.py

```
    class User(AbstractUser, BaseModel):
        full_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        addresss=models.CharField(max_length=40)
        phoneno=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        email=models.EmailField()
        gender=models.IntegerField(choices=gender_choice,default='0')

class Student(BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    father_name=models.CharField(max_length=64)
    mother_name=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    date_of_birth=models.DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.full_name
```

2.Serializers.py

```
class UserPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=('full_name','addresss','gender','id')
##Serializer Class for Student 
class StudentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = UserPostSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model=Student
        fields=(
            'id',
            # 'father_name',
            # 'mother_name',
            # 'date_of_birth',
            'user',
            )
```

4.Views.py

```
class StudentViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer

    http_methods = ['get', 'post','put','delete']


    def create(self, request):

        serializer=StudentSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid()
        row = serializer.data
        user = row['user']
        full_name = user['full_name']
        first_name = full_name.split(' ')[0]

        # email = first_name + '@schoolX.com'

        # _e = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        # if _e:
        #     email = first_name + str(+count) + '@schoolX.com'
        emailpattern =  '{}(\d*)@schoolx.com'.format(first_name)
        count = User.objects.filter(email__iregex=emailpattern).count()

        if count > 0:
            email = '{}{}@schoolx.com'.format(first_name, str(count))




        user,created = User.objects.get_or_create(email= email, 
            defaults={'full_name':row['user']['full_name'],'addresss':row['user']['addresss']})
        student = Student.objects.create(user_id=user.id)

        return Response({'email':email})
```

4.Urls.py

```
    router.register(r'students', views.StudentViewset)
```

when i try to add student it shows error like this;;

```
Internal Server Error: /students/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dinesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/dinesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/dinesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/dinesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dinesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dinesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/dinesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/dinesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dinesh/Desktop/pro1/pro1/app1/views.py", line 50, in create
    user,created = User.objects.get_or_create(email= email,
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'email' referenced before assignment
[25/Jul/2018 12:04:05] "POST /students/ HTTP/1.1" 500 14800
```

Then How can  i fix this error ??I tried it with many more ideas but i cant fix it ..Anyone of u plz help  To fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncomment this line -

```
# email = first_name + '@schoolX.com'
```

Or set email to empty -

```
email = ''
```

Check if your `count > 0` because if it's not, then you won't have a `email` variable assigned and that's why

```
local variable 'email' referenced before assignment
```

You are referencing `email` in line -

```
user,created = User.objects.get_or_create(email= email,...
```

Before assigning it if `count < 0`

Comment: it works but again if i click same name the in shows error like this:UNIQUE constraint failed: app1_user.username

Comment: Can you explain more @DineshKc ?

Comment: sir  can u   help me by solving with teamviewer, i will give u id and password , plz sir ,

Comment: I can help you here @DineshKc, just explain the problem that you are seeing now

Comment: my models.py,views.py all are same as i explained above,when i uncomment this like as u told then , It shows error like this ........"""py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/dinesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: app1_user.username
[25/Jul/2018 13:10:24] "POST /students/ HTTP/1.1" 500 18999
"" What type of error is this and how can i fix it?????

Comment: Google this error, you'll find it easily. It's related to your models @DineshKc